# How can I reference a word in a dynamic cell for parameter 2 instead of having a fixed word in single quotes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want whatever value I enter into this cell - Sheet 2 Column D1 - to become part of my formula. And I need to be able to duplicate the sheets and have the "sheet 2" reference update to the duplicated sheet. Is this impossible?

`=QUERY(Tasks!A3:K,"select C,A,D,K where E='Name from cell in Sheet 2 Column D1' and  B='Ready' Order By D,C",0)`

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

To include reference to a cell add some quotes ' "&Sheet2!D1&" '

```
=QUERY(Tasks!A3:K,"select C,A,D,K where E='"&Sheet2!D1&"' and  B='Ready' Order By D,C",0)
```